# select2 set selected value to a hidden field

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 function like below,

```
    function select2AutocompleteManyToManyField(field, request_url){
        var map = {};
        $("#"+field).select2({
            multiple: true,
            placeholder: field,
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper

                url: request_url,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        query: term
                    };
                },
            results: function (data) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                var objects = [];
                $.each(data,function(i,obj){
                    map[obj.translations__name] = obj;
                    objects.push({
                        "text": obj.translations__name,
                        'id': map[obj.translations__name].id

                    });
                });
                return {results: objects};
              }
            }
        });
}
```

I want to update a another hidden field's value with the selected fields id's.
Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been through this and could not find a solution. then I worked itout as below
on you sunbmit click populate the hidden field

```
 $("#mysubmit").click(function () {
            $('#Hiddenfields').val($('#divforselect').val());
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way I saw somewhere here and successfully applied:

```
            /* bind select2 */
            var select2 = $( '#city' ).select2({
                initSelection : function( element, callback ) {
                    var data = { id: element.val(), text: element.val() };
                    callback(data);
                },
                minimumInputLength: 2,
                ajax: {
                    url: "/city",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: function( term, page ){
                            return {
                                q: term,
                                page_limit: 10
                        };
                    },
                    results: function( data, page ){
                        return { results: data.content.result };
                    }
                },
            }).data( 'select2' );
            select2.onSelect = ( function( fn ){
                return function( data, options ){
                    $( '#city_id' ).val( data.id );
                    return fn.apply( this, arguments )
                };
            })( select2.onSelect );
```

Comment: @RabNawaz There is no such an event. You are right. That is why it is created in this example. Examine it please.